# Twilio not sending SMS

Tags: c#, asp.net, twilio

I've tried this code

```
string AccountSid = "[mySID]"; 
string AuthToken = "[myAuthCode]"; 

var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);

var me = twilio.SendMessage("+15016536555", "+923355216606", "A blank txt");
Console.WriteLine(me.Sid);
```

I put my original SID and AuthToken in my code. The *me.Sid* is giving **null**.
Moreover, the **To** number is also registered.

I noted that the **To** and **From** in *me* variable is empty.Their is only send and recieve date and time.

[image]

Comment: is an exception thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it worked fine when To and From numbers were valid. I could receive the text. However, when I changed the From number it failed and reproduced the same problem. It didn't throw an exception, just failed silently.

Interesting thing is there is a RestException property in the message object which displayed "The From phone number +xxxxxxxxxx is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone number or short code for your account." This way it was easy to identify the problem.

I installed Twilio wrapper from NuGet

```
Install-Package Twilio
```

and the version I've just tried is 4.0.3

If your version is out of date, update it to the latest version so you can check the error using RestException property.

UPDATE:
The message object and RestException in my application looks like this:
[image]

Comment: I had already installed twilio lib v.4.0.3. And also their is no exception at all!

Comment: I added the image of how I see the exception. It's weird you don't have the RestException property in your response

Comment: @Jamil maybe contacting their support seems a legit option here? https://www.twilio.com/help/contact

Comment: Also the **twilio.SendMessage** is returning null.

Comment: Well, you can try to capture the request with Fiddler or Wireshark to ensure a request is actually being made. Alternatively you can make the same request via their REST API again with Fiddler, bypassing the C# wrapper.

Comment: I used Fiddler. The POST and GET request is made successfully.

Comment: Well, I cannot think of anything else. I have Twilio.Api library referenced in my project and Message class derives from TwilioBase which has a RestException property. Can you check the Twilio.Api library with Object Explorer and verify this hierarchy exists in the library you use?

Comment: Twilio.Api not showing up in Object browser window!

Comment: Ah I see. I was using Visual Studio 2015 and it shows parent variables among the childs'. In VS 2013 check the base at the top of the list you should be able to see RestException there (assuming it's not null which is the case in your original question)

Comment: Its sending sms using test credentials and magic number as **From**.

Comment: Well, sorry I tried but I don't have any more ideas. I think your best bet is to check out the RestException which should be among the base variables.